# FirebaseAuth.getInstance() always return null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I know I can see so many questions on this topic on stackoverflow and I have tried almost all of them and haven't worked yet so this is my only option to post a new question.

My problem is FirebaseAuth.getInstance always return null even though I have initialized the FirebaseApp. My main purpose is to use phone authenticaiton from firebase and I have enabled it in firebase console.

Things I have done-

- Built firebase project in firebase console
- Added SHA-1 key
- downloaded the json file and added it to app level in my android project
- Multiple times of invalidate/restart in android studio
- Multiple times of debugging while trying to getInstance of firebaseAuth in different activity life cycle functions
- Tried to integrate FirebaseUI but still getInstance returns null and firebaseUI does not even start
- changing different version of FirebaseAuth
- checking dependencies in gradle file again and again

App Level Gradle

```
//apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ajoobee.mm"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta2'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.0.0-rc02'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'

    //add kotlin
    /* implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.1"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"*/

    implementation "com.github.leonardoxh:retrofit2-livedata-adapter:1.1.2"

    //Internet Checker
    implementation 'com.treebo:internetavailabilitychecker:1.0.2'

    // Retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'

    //Android Jetpack
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.1.0'
//    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"

    //ButterKnife
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.0'

    //Dagger implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.17'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.17'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.17'

    /* Dagger2 - default dependency */
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.17'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'

    //circle image view
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.1'
    //room database
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0'
    annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.1.0'

    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.1'

    //ImagePicker and Glide
    implementation group: 'com.zhihu.android', name: 'matisse', version: '0.5.2'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'

    //SummerNote
    implementation 'in.nashapp.androidsummernote:androidsummernote:1.0.5'

    //uCrop
    implementation 'com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.4-native'

    //roundedImageView
    implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'

    //progressBarChart
    implementation 'com.ramijemli.percentagechartview:percentagechartview:0.3.1'

    //googleLocation
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0"
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.0.0'

    //implementation project(':multiselectspinner')
    implementation 'com.droidninja:filepicker:2.2.1'

    //firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

my project level Gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    //ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.30'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.30"
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
        classpath 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:1.0.0'
        classpath 'androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'



        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My Fragment

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;
import androidx.navigation.NavOptions;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
import android.text.style.ClickableSpan;
import android.text.style.ForegroundColorSpan;
import android.text.style.UnderlineSpan;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.ajoobee.mm.Constants;
import com.ajoobee.mm.Data.Network.Response.ServerResult;
import com.ajoobee.mm.Data.Network.Retrofit.AuthenticationInterceptor;
import com.ajoobee.mm.Employer.UI.Home.Profile.PopUpWindow.CityPopUpWindow;
import com.ajoobee.mm.Employer.UI.Home.Profile.UpdateCompanyViewModel;
import com.ajoobee.mm.JobSeeker.UI.Home.Profile.JobSeekerProfileViewModel;
import com.ajoobee.mm.R;
import com.ajoobee.mm.Util.ErrorDialog;
import com.ajoobee.mm.Util.Util;
import com.ajoobee.mm.ViewModelFactory;
import com.ajoobee.mm.databinding.JobseekerFragmentRegisterBinding;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseException;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import dagger.android.support.AndroidSupportInjection;

public class JobSeekerRegisterFragment extends Fragment {

    private JobseekerFragmentRegisterBinding binding;
    private JobSeekerProfileViewModel jobSeekerProfileViewModel;
    private UpdateCompanyViewModel updateCompanyViewModel;
    private CityPopUpWindow cityPopUpWindow;
    private int city;
    private boolean first = true;
    private ErrorDialog errorDialog;

    @Inject
    ViewModelFactory viewModelFactory;

    @Inject
    AuthenticationInterceptor authenticationInterceptor;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.jobseeker_fragment_register, container, false);
        init();

        if(this.getContext() != null){
            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this.getContext());
            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        }

        return binding.getRoot();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if(firebaseUser != null){
            Toast.makeText(this.getContext(), "Already Sign in ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this.getContext(), "mAuth Still null ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void init() {

        if (this.getActivity() != null) {

            if (this.getActivity().getIntent() != null) {
                Intent intent = this.getActivity().getIntent();
                if (intent.getBooleanExtra(Constants.LOGIN, false)) {

                    NavOptions navOptions = new NavOptions.Builder()
                            .setPopUpTo(R.id.jobSeekerEmailVeriRequiredFragment, true)
                            .build();

                    Navigation.findNavController(JobSeekerRegisterFragment.this.getActivity(), R.id.fragment).navigate(R.id.jobSeekerEmailVeriRequiredFragment, new Bundle(), navOptions);

                }
            }
        }

        if (this.getContext() != null) {
            errorDialog = new ErrorDialog(this.getContext(), new ErrorDialog.OkButtonClick() {
                @Override
                public void onOkClick() {

                }
            });

            binding.txtCity.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(() -> {
                if (first) {
                    cityPopUpWindow = new CityPopUpWindow(this.getContext(), binding.txtCity, city, id -> {
                        city = id;
                        cityPopUpWindow.dismiss();
                        cityPopUpWindow.opened = false;
                        binding.dropDownImageView.animate().rotation(0).start();
                    });
                    first = false;
                }
            });

            jobSeekerProfileViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(JobSeekerProfileViewModel.class);
            updateCompanyViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(UpdateCompanyViewModel.class);

            //ClickableSpan

            SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(getString(R.string.jobseeker_signup_already_account));
            ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(@NonNull View widget) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), JobSeekerLogin.class);
                    JobSeekerRegisterFragment.this.startActivity(intent);
                }
            };
            spannableString.setSpan(clickableSpan, 25, 30, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            spannableString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(getResources().getColor(R.color.activeControlColor)), 25, 30, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            spannableString.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, spannableString.length(), 0);

            binding.alreadyHaveAccountTextView.setText(spannableString);
            binding.alreadyHaveAccountTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
            binding.alreadyHaveAccountTextView.setHighlightColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

            //ClickableSpan

            //ClickListener
            binding.txtCity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    cityPopUpWindow.show();

                    if (cityPopUpWindow.opened) {
                        binding.dropDownImageView.animate().rotation(180).start();
                    } else {
                        binding.dropDownImageView.animate().rotation(0).start();
                    }
                }
            });

            binding.btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

//                    if (CheckCondition()) {
//                        sendToRegister();
//                    }

                    getVerificationCode();

                }
            });
            //ClickListener

            //City
            updateCompanyViewModel.Api_City();
            updateCompanyViewModel.observeCity().observe(this, listServerResult -> {
                if (listServerResult != null) {
                    if (listServerResult.getResponse().getCode().equals("200")) {
                        if (cityPopUpWindow != null) {
                            if (cityPopUpWindow.cityPopUpAdapter != null) {
                                cityPopUpWindow.cityPopUpAdapter.addCity(listServerResult.getResult());
                                cityPopUpWindow.cityPopUpAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            //City

            //Registration
            jobSeekerProfileViewModel.observeRegistration().observe(this, new Observer<ServerResult<JsonObject>>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(ServerResult<JsonObject> jsonObjectServerResult) {
                    if (jsonObjectServerResult != null) {
                        if (jsonObjectServerResult.getResponse().getCode().equals("200")) {

                            if (jsonObjectServerResult.getResult() != null) {
                                if (jsonObjectServerResult.getResult().size() > 0) {

                                    JsonObject jsonObject = jsonObjectServerResult.getResult().get(0);

                                    if (JobSeekerRegisterFragment.this.getActivity() != null) {
                                        authenticationInterceptor.tokenId = jsonObject.get("token").getAsString();
                                        Navigation.findNavController(JobSeekerRegisterFragment.this.getActivity(), R.id.fragment).navigate(R.id.action_jobSeekerRegisterFragment_to_jobSeekerEmailVerificationFragment);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            errorDialog.updateTitleAndShow(jsonObjectServerResult.getResponse().getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            //Registration
        }
    }

    private boolean CheckCondition() {

        if (this.getContext() != null) {
            if (Util.checkConnection(this.getContext())) {

                if (binding.txtContactInfoEmail.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {

                    errorDialog.updateTitleAndShow(getString(R.string.signup_error_missing_email_or_phone));
                    return false;
                } else {

                    if (!Util.checkEmail(binding.txtContactInfoEmail.getText().toString())) {

                        if (!Util.checkPhoneNumber(binding.txtContactInfoEmail.getText().toString())) {
                            errorDialog.updateTitleAndShow(getString(R.string.signup_error_missing_email_phone_valid));
                            return false;
                        }
                    }

                }

                if (binding.txtFullName.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    errorDialog.updateTitleAndShow(getString(R.string.signup_error_missing_full_name));
                    return false;
                }

                if (binding.txtPasword.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    errorDialog.updateTitleAndShow(getString(R.string.signup_error_missing_password));
                    return false;
                } else {
                    if (binding.txtPasword.getText().toString().length() < 6 || !Util.checkPassword(binding.txtPasword.getText().toString())) {

                        errorDialog.updateTitleAndShow(getString(R.string.signup_error_password_character));
                        return false;

                    }
                }

                if (binding.txtConfirmPassword.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    errorDialog.updateTitleAndShow(getString(R.string.signup_error_confirm_password));
                    return false;
                }

                if (binding.txtCity.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    errorDialog.updateTitleAndShow(getString(R.string.signup_error_missing_location));
                    return false;
                }

                if (!binding.txtPasword.getText().toString().equals(binding.txtConfirmPassword.getText().toString())) {
                    errorDialog.updateTitleAndShow(getString(R.string.signup_error_missing_password_match));
                    return false;
                }

                return true;

            } else {
                errorDialog.updateTitleAndShow(getResources().getString(R.string.no_internet_connection));
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void getVerificationCode() {

        if(mAuth != null){
            PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance(mAuth).verifyPhoneNumber(
                    "09798423585",        // Phone number to verify
                    60,                 // Timeout duration
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
                    this.getActivity(),               // Activity (for callback binding)
                    new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
                        @Override
                        public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Verification Completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onVerificationFailed(@NonNull FirebaseException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Verification failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
        }

    }

    private void sendToRegister() {
        com.ajoobee.mm.Data.Obj.JobSeeker.JobSeekerRegister jobSeekerRegister = new com.ajoobee.mm.Data.Obj.JobSeeker.JobSeekerRegister(
                binding.txtFullName.getText().toString(),
                binding.txtPasword.getText().toString(),
                binding.txtContactInfoEmail.getText().toString(),
                "",
                "",
                "",
                "1",
                ""
        );

        if (this.getActivity() != null) {
            ((JobSeekerRegisterActivity) this.getActivity()).email = binding.txtContactInfoEmail.getText().toString();
        }

        jobSeekerProfileViewModel.Api_JobSeekerRegistration(jobSeekerRegister);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this);
    }
}
```

Error Message

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()' on a null object reference
```

You can see that I tried to get current user onStart function but it ever failed. I debugged every lines and mAuth is always null.

Comment: When you say it's always null are you basing that off your "mAuth Still null" toast message?

Comment: On Debugging. Let me upload the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the answer, it was because of the

```
tools:node="replace"
```

in the manifest. Just remove it and it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

fix this method:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();


    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();//here u must have 
//instance first then use the method

    if(firebaseUser != null){
        Toast.makeText(this.getContext(), "Already Sign in ", 
 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this.getContext(), "mAuth Still null ", 
 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

code below will work correct for u

```
  @Override
  public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this.getContext());
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = getInstance(); //first try without this line
    firebaseUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

    if(firebaseUser != null){
        Toast.makeText(this.getContext(), "Already Sign in ", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this.getContext(), "mAuth Still null ", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sry, mAuth is still null and crashed the app. Btw, I think I won't need the instance of firebase user before using method. Is it really necessary?

Comment: no, it’s not cause issue for you in this code.'mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();' this is Null, check the 'getInstance()' method.

Comment: ahh sry my mistake, getInstance returns null and it is the firebase library function so I can't debug into it.